# Helmet Express ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200

Tags: express, cors, helmet.js, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

please I need help, I checked on all google and not get really answer for to open my issue.
I want to use helmet to secure my express server. But when I am using it I get this error : ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200 for loaded my images from my database.
this is my server express :

```
// Initialize server
const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors())
app.use(helmet())

// CORS configuration
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

I am getting my images from my database so the url in localhost is :  http://localhost:3000/image/<name_image>

When i am not using helmet all works fine.

Please any help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**tl;dr: disable [the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy), enabled by default in Helmet v5.**

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
    // ...
  })
);
```

---

Helmet maintainer here.

Helmet sets the [the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy) to `require-corp`.

Setting this header means that loading cross-origin resources (like an image from another resource) is trickier. For example, loading a cross-origin like this...

```html
<img alt="My picture" src="https://example.com/image.png">
```

...won't work unless `example.com` explicitly allows it, by setting some response headers of its own. Your browser will try to load `example.com/image.png`, and if it's not explicitly allowed, your browser will drop the response.

To fix this, you can prevent Helmet from setting the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` header, like this:

```js
app.use(
  helmet({
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
    // ...
  })
);
```

I made [a small sample app](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-rain-flk19?file=/src/index.js) you can use to play around with this. In my testing, it doesn't seem to work in HTTP but it *does* over HTTPS, which might explain why things only break in production.

Comment: i tried the above workaround but still the same error

Comment: in react app if you don't add crossorigin="true" to img tag, it won't work

Comment: I added this flag but I still need the `crossorigin` tag on embedded images to access. I do not want this. How can make it work without needing that tag?

Comment: @MoteZart It's possible that this is happening because you need to do a hard refresh in your browser. Does that fix things?

Comment: For a requested asset to work inside an html image (on a browser) I needed `app.use(helmet({
    crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,

  }));`

Comment: In reactjs app, @MoteZart your answer works for me. Thanks

Comment: @HakimAsa - You deserve some sort of award!!

Comment: It appears to be disabled by default for `v7.1.0`.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem, this fixed it:

```
helmet({
    crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
})
```

Comment: fyi, this didn't work for me, i had to use the solution in accepted answer `crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,`, see also:  https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/343#issuecomment-1006259994

Comment: wrap that in app.use()

Answer (score 2):

If versioning is a better option for you, I had this same issue on helmet `>=5.0.0`. Dropping to `4.6.0` solved this error.

Answer (score 1):

After a long look on google  I get the solution from here :
https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/176
I add this line :

```
res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy', 'same-site');
```

and just do refresh and clear cache (cmd + R on MAC and ctrl+R on others) and it's worked like a charm.
Thanks [Evan Hahn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804100/evan-hahn)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used that way

```
    helmet({
      crossOriginResourcePolicy: false,
    })
```

The issue is with the cross-origin resource policy which should be same-site as the browser treats as another origin.

Comment: fyi, this didn't work for me, i had to use the solution in accepted answer `crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,`, see also:  https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/343#issuecomment-1006259994

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot, and none of the solutions above didn't work for me, unfortunately. But in the end, I found this solution:

```
// Helmet for the security
server.use(helmet());

// Static File Serving Access for Uploads
server.use("/uploads",
    express.static(path.join(env.UPLOADS_BASE_PATH, "uploads"), {
    setHeaders: (res) => {
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", env.CLIENT_URL);
    },
  }),
);

// Cors Origin for Client Access
const corsOptions = {
  origin: env.CLIENT_URL,
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

server.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Just change the `env.UPLOADS_BASE_PATH` and `env.CLIENT_URL` variables and the "uploads" route for your preferences. It seems that route settings were not being applied correctly. With this update, it ensures that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set for the static file responses. (server is Express btw.)

I hope this will help someone too. Good luck.

**P.S: Most important part was setting the header for my static route. Cors options can be simple than that.**